# SPRING MONGO-DATA 1.4.0.RC1->1.4.0.RELEASE: "Can not set String field id to java.lang.Integer"

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

i am desperately trying to remove the 1.4.0.RC1 spring-data-mongo to at least 1.4.0.RELEASE of the spring data ....

the problem i now run into is:

we use a String as @id field in our domain objects

```
public class AbstractDocument implements Identifiable<String> {

@Id
@Indexed(unique = true, background = true)
private String id;

public AbstractDocument() {
    id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
@Override
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

so, nothing special here, BUT i then get this strange
"Can not set java.lang.String field AbstractDocument.id to java.lang.Integer"
error, i tried providing a setter with Integer input, but no change, any suggestions what i am doing wrong here and how i can circumvent it?!

it is strange because in the database are just string-id fields :/ and too bad this happens just on the update from RC1 (which should not have been used in first place, sure ) to RELEASE of same version ;(

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field ...core.domain.AbstractDocument.id to java.lang.Integer
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:379)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getField(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BeanWrapper.getProperty(BeanWrapper.java:133)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.createDBRef(MappingMongoConverter.java:772)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.toDBRef(MappingMongoConverter.java:307)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.createDbRefFor(QueryMapper.java:338)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.convertAssociation(QueryMapper.java:329)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.convertAssociation(QueryMapper.java:296)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedKeyword(QueryMapper.java:193)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObjectForField(QueryMapper.java:136)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObject(QueryMapper.java:114)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1514)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1506)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:532)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery$Execution.readCollection(AbstractMongoQuery.java:147)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery$CollectionExecution.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:170)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:91)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:337)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
```